# Link on image, opacity hover on image

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have an image, which i have an opacity on if I hover over the image, done with CSS.

I also have a link showing up on top of the image if the user hover over the image, to make the link show up Im using jQuery.

But when I hover over the link which shows up when I hover the image the whole opacity effect and the link is behaving shaky when I move the cursor over the link.

My explanation is that this occurs because when I have the cursor over the link, Im actually no longer over the image. But how do I solve this the neatest way? To get the link to behave properly and the opacity of the image to be set when I have the cursor over the link.

My code looks like this:
HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2 category-product">
    <img src="image1.png" data-img="product-image-1">
    <div class="category-product-overview"><a href="#">Overview</a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 category-product">
    <img src="image2.png" data-img="product-image-2">
    <div class="category-product-overview"><a href="#">Overview</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.category-product {
    width: 205px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.category-product-overview {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    top: 35%;
    bottom: 65%;
    left: 29%;
}

.category-product-overview a {
    padding: 9px 16px 9px 16px;
    background-color: #41a5e0;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
    color: #fff;
}

.category-product-overview a:hover {
    color: #348dc1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.category-product img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.category-product img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
```

jQuery

```
$('div.category-product > img').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('.category-product-overview').show(); //hover in
}, function() {
    $(this).next('.category-product-overview').hide(); //hover out
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.category-product img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
```

to

```
.category-product:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
```

that way the `:hover` is attached to the parent of both the image and the overview, so it doesn't matter which one the mouse is over, as long as it's inside the category parent.

and the javascript

```
$('.category-product').hover(function() {
    $('.category-product-overview', this).show();
}, function() {
    $('.category-product-overview', this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Tried to change to the above, but the same shaky "effect" occurs when I move the mouse over the link.

Comment: @JohnF - You should probably change the JS to match, added.